# Background parallax not working on image from a database

Tags: jquery, html, background-image, parallax

I am using [this plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/High-Performance-Background-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-CSS3-jarallax.html) for creating a parallax effect on the background image. The static code is working, but the images which come from a database are not working.

The last three images are working which I added directly, but inside the `while` loop the background images do not have the parallax effect.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smoothscroll/1.4.0/SmoothScroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/High-Performance-Background-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-CSS3-jarallax/jarallax/jarallax.js"></script>

<?php 
  $i = 1;
  while ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
    <div class="jarallax" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.25),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)),url(assets/images/products-list/<?php echo $background_img;?>);background-position: center;"></div>
    <?php $i++; 
  }
  $stmt->close();
?>

<!--below are the images working with parallax-->
<div class="jarallax" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911073-52527ac43761?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);"></div>
<div class="jarallax" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911073-52527ac43761?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);"></div>
<div class="jarallax" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911073-52527ac43761?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jarallax').jarallax({
    speed: 0.5,
    imgWidth: 1366,
    imgHeight: 768
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.jarallax {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

HTML view source (Changed images)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jarallax').jarallax({
    speed: 0.5,
    imgWidth: 1366,
    imgHeight: 768
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.jarallax {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/favicon.png">
  <title>Product Category</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jarallax" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.25),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)),url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568745814386-e7241cd58169?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);background-position: center;"></div>
  <div class="jarallax" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.25),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)),url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911073-52527ac43761?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);background-position: center;"></div>
  <div class="jarallax" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.25),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)),url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911073-52527ac43761?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);background-position: center;"></div>

  <div class="jarallax" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911073-52527ac43761?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);"> </div>
  <div class="jarallax" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911073-52527ac43761?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);"></div>
  <div class="jarallax" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911073-52527ac43761?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smoothscroll/1.4.0/SmoothScroll.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/High-Performance-Background-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-CSS3-jarallax/jarallax/jarallax.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Given that the images are all generated on the server, there is absolutely no difference between them on the client side. It would seem that if it doesn't work on the PHP generated images, then there's something wrong with either the image, or how you are defining its `img` element

Comment: Do you see any error on console ?

Comment: does your `$background_img;` have any spaces/other special characters?

Comment: @Casper, There is no error in the console.

Comment: @cloned, No there is no space. my image name is slider1.png, slider2.png, slider3.png

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Images are correct. There is no issue, I checked on the local system. I am not defining img I am using a background image.

Comment: You're right, I meant `div` element. Can you edit the question with the actual HTML output, as the PHP seems irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, You mean view source code?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. I found the solution the issue is with linear-gradient. If I remove then it's working.

Comment: Glad you found the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Is there any other option to add linear-gradient on image?

Comment: On? You mean over the top of the image?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yes, because of background-image: linear-gradient is not working

Comment: Well what you have should work, although note that for the gradient to appear on top of the image you need to put it last in the list in your CSS. However it appears that the parallax library doesn't work with it, so this is moot. You can't do it. An alternative would be to put the gradient on another element in the `div`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thanks for the help. I will try this.